# How can I make this circuit as a module?

Tags: tikz-circuit-lib

I started to use [the `circ` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/generic/diagrams/circ) and I would like to draw this kind of black box, but the final result is unsatisfactory: how can I take advantage of LaTeX principles in this kind of code? For example, the square is not precise and I would like to add the arrows and other symbols inside the square.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[basic,box,gate,oldgate,ic,optics,physics]{circ}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\newcommand{\degr}{degr}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{circuit}1
\- 20 l
\- 20 u
\- 20 r
\- 20 d
\at{-19} {17}
\centertext CMD from { } to { }
\at{-20} {17}
\bundle { } 10 l
\at{-20} {10}
\bundle {1} 10 l
\at{-19} {10}
\centertext DSI from { } to { }
\at{-20} {3}
\bundle {64} 10 l
\at{-19} {3}
\centertext DATAIN from { } to { }
\at{0} {16}
\bundle {1} 10 r
\at{-4} {16}
\centertext DSO from { } to { }
\at{0} {12}
\bundle {1} 10 r
\at{-4} {12}
\centertext ERR from { } to { }
\at{0} {8}
\bundle {1} 10 r
\at{-4} {8}
\centertext ACK from { } to { }
\at{0} {4}
\bundle {64} 10 r
\at{-5} {4}
\centertext DOUT from { } to { }
\at{-10} {10}
\centertext BLACKBOX from { } to { }
\at{-18} {0.3}
\centertext $\bigtriangleup$ from { } to { }
\at{-17.4} {0}
\- 5 d 
\centertext CLK from { } to { }
\at{-14} {-0.6}
\centertext $\bigcirc$ from { } to { }
\at{-13.4} {-1.2}
\- 5 d 
\centertext RST from { } to { }
\end{circuit}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Can you please post an image (or a link to one) showing exactly what kind of diagram are you planning to obtain?

Comment: As Gonzalo says, it's not clear what you actually want here.